# using Que as a heroku worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, heroku-postgres, que

I am using https://github.com/chanks/que

I am having problem setting up `que` in heroku. I have setup `web` and `worker` process in heroku and I have these configurations:

`config/initializers/que.rb`

```
Que.wake_interval = 10.seconds
# Que.mode = (ENV['QUE_MODE'] or Rails.env.production? ? :async : :off).to_sym
Que.mode = :off
Que.worker_count = (ENV['QUE_WORKERS'] || 1)
```

`Procfile`

```
web: bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV
worker: bundle exec rake que:work
```

Previously, when I had only one `web` process in heroku and `Que.mode = :async` `que` was running successfully within same `web` process.

Now that I setup seperate `worker` process for it, I tried using `Que.mode = :off` and I can't see any que logs, and I can see all the failing jobs in `que-web`.

Please let me know what I am missing, and which `Que.mode` will be suitable in my configuration.

**NOTE**: I want to keep `web` and `worker` process seperate and `worker` should be responsible for running my `que` jobs only.

Comment: Removed the [que] tag, which is a misspelled version of [queue].  I did not add [queue] because the question seems to be about a specific queue implementation named "Que" (for which there is no tag), but not really about the "queue" data structure.

Comment: Ok Thanks @JohnBollinger